# How do you get the image from message and display it in an embed discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get the user's image from a message and display it in an embed, but for some reason it didn't work

I used the same code for author/footer icon and it worked with no problems, I don't understand why this didn't work

```py
if len(message.attachments) > 0:
    attachment = message.attachments[0]
    if attachment.filename.endswith(".jpg") or attachment.filename.endswith(".jpeg") or attachment.filename.endswith(".png") or attachment.filename.endswith(".webp") or attachment.filename.endswith(".gif"):
        self.image = attachment.url
    elif "https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net" in message.content or "https://tenor.com/view/" in message.content:
        self.image = message.content

# In a separate function

e = discord.Embed()
e.set_image(url=self.image)
```

I tried printing `self.image` and I got the url, so I don't know why it isn't working (the same thing is happening to thumbnails btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "separate function" must be in the same class as the place you check for the message attachment. I have made this "other function" a command to send the embed to the channel and it worked fine. The class is a discord Cog.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if len(message.attachments) > 0:
            attachment = message.attachments[0]
        else:
            return
        if attachment.filename.endswith(".jpg") or attachment.filename.endswith(".jpeg") or attachment.filename.endswith(".png") or attachment.filename.endswith(".webp") or attachment.filename.endswith(".gif"):
            self.image = attachment.url
        elif "https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net" in message.content or "https://tenor.com/view/" in message.content:
            self.image = message.content

    @commands.command(name="t")
    async def other_function(self, ctx):
        e = discord.Embed()
        e.set_image(url=self.image)
        await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

Of course, you need to have a setup function as well.

```py
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(test(bot)) #Replace "test" with the name of your class
```

Because the "test" class is a Cog you need to load it from your main file.

```py
bot.load_extension('cog_file') #without the ".py" extension
```